# Ruby on Rails: How to model a "user favorite model"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

I'll use StackOverflow as my example. Let's say I have a `Question` model. A logged in user can "star" a `Question` to mark is as one of their favorites. In the database, this sort of thing would probably be stored in a `UserQuestions` table with a `user_id` field and a `question_id` field. This sort of feature is not typical CRUD since there is really only "list", "add", and "delete". Also the records being displayed on the  "User starred questions" list should be not `UserQuestion` records but instead `Question` records. What code do I put in my controller and `UserQuestion` model?

```
class MyFavoriteQuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    #list just the questions associated with current_user
  end

  def add
    #insert a row in the database for current_user and selected question
  def

  def remove
    #remove the row from the database
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say this is typical crud if you stick with convention. Add is create, remove is destroy.

```
class FavouritesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :find_user

  def index
    @favourites = @user.favourites
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.find params[:id]
    @user.favourites << @question
  def

  def destroy
    @favourite = @user.favourites.find_by_question_id params[:id]
    @favourite.destroy unless @favourite.blank?
  end
end


#routes.rb

resources :users do
  resources :favourites, :only => [:index, :create, :destroy]
end

#user.rb

has_many :user_favourites, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :favourites, :through => :user_favourites, :source => :question
```

Comment: I haven't seen this syntax before in any tutorials that I've read: `@user.favourites << @question`. Does this save the User model? Or do I still need to do that?

Comment: Also, how would you link to the "create" action? Eventually, I plan on doing an AJAX request to POST to the "create" action, but what can I do so that this works without javascript?

Comment: The assignment does save the association. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference The create action I'd have as a button_to with remote => true and using rails 3 javscript helpers. See http://asciicasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

Comment: I keep getting a "stack level too deep" error and can't figure out why that is. I think it has something to do with the model associations.

Comment: Ah nevermind, figured it out. I had duplicate `:has_many :user_favorites`